# How to block viewer from scrolling horizontally on a web page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, screen-resolution

I was given a very complicated design with a large background, so I had to come up with a little script to resize the screen on smaller screens to center and remove white spaces and remove horizontal scrollbar.

Now this is the Jscript snippet I wrote for screen resizing:

```
(function() {
    if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1024 && jQuery(window).width() <= 1275 ) {
      jQuery('html').css({"margin-left":"-180px"});
       jQuery('html').css({"overflow-x":'hidden'});

    }


    else if(jQuery(window).width() == 1280) {
      jQuery('html').css({"margin-left":"-52px"});
         jQuery('html').css({"overflow-x":'hidden'});    
    }

     else if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1300 || jQuery(window).width() <= 1400 ) {
      jQuery('html').css({"margin-left":"-0"});
         jQuery('html').css({"overflow-x":'hidden'});    
    }

    else if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1430 ) {
      jQuery('html').css({"margin-right":"-60px"});
         jQuery('html').css({"overflow-x":'hidden'});    
    }

    else if(jQuery(window).width() < 940 ) {
      jQuery('html').css({"margin-left":"0"});
       jQuery('html').css({"overflow-x":'visible'});
    }

    else {


}
})();
```

now if a user still uses a touch screen they can scroll to right side of the page.

Is there any chance if I can block that ? like not the user scroll horizontally by any chance ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a couple of code suggestions: 1. `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` will allow shorthand use of the $ sign without any conflict; 2. store `$(window).width()` as a variable, given that you reference it a lot; 3. combine your `css()` calls like so: `.css({'margin-left': -180px', 'overflow-x': 'hidden'})`. Just for optimization. I know this doesn't answer your question, of course. Lastly: make sure all of this goes in a `$(window).resize()` event so that if the window is resized, it responds.

Comment: Also: could you post, say, your work so far, or maybe a preview of what the design is to look like? It seems like the problem would more appropriately be solved by CSS media queries, without JavaScript at all.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing to say: you're setting `overflow-x` to `visible` for small resolutions, which is why there is a problem in the first place. Maybe you should explicitly set the width of the `body` element instead? Again, hard to determine without seeing how the actual design flows.

Comment: @MMiller thanks for the suggestion, but $ doesn't work when it's for a WordPress theme. and for uploading the website, it still is undergoing production, not complete at all.

Comment: `(function($) { $(document).ready(function () { $('body').css('background-color', 'red'); }); })(jQuery);` <-- Try it. The `function($) {` part is an anonymous function and everything is encapsulated within. The `})(jQuery)` part provides a parameter to the function, the `jQuery` object, which is created with `noConflict()` in WordPress. This code will work anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS and this to your CSS file:

```
html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

If you want to disable scrolling then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907808/how-to-disable-horizontal-dragging-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/12671092#12671092) would help you.

> I found I could fix it by finding/fixing/removing elements that were
>   wider than the width. For instance, if you have a 100% width on your
>   container, and then an element inside has 100% width with margin or
>   padding, even if the overflow is hidden on the container, the page
>   will drag from side to side.
>
> If you can make sure your elements inside don't horizontally spill
>   outside the container, the page won't drag. If you need padding on a
>   percentage width inside the container (like one element with 100%
>   width, or two with 50% or whatever), 'box-sizing: border-box;' is the
>   way forward.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added that, but still if I open the web page on a touch screen I can scroll horizontally .

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be able to do this fairly simple without the need for Javascript hacks. I've used this method before on a variety of websites.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="outer header">
            <div class="main header">
                <div class="inner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer-wrapper {
    background: transparent url("../images/background-header.png") no-repeat center top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 950px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background: transparent url("../images/background-navigation.png") no-repeat center top;
    height: 254px;
}

#wrapper, .outer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 950px;
}

.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
}

.inner {
    float: left;
    width: 950px;
}
```

For a real life example see this site: www.levidealmansion.com and pay special attention to the "vines" that appear behind the logo and the navigation and how you never get a horizontal overflow even if you do shrink the browser ... at least down to 960px.