# white blank space when i get out of my site borders on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, web, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Is there any way to prevent user view go out of "render zone"? Or prevent this problem of trimmed view? I used xCode emulator for iPhone 4, safari browser.

[white blank space when i get out of my site borders on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzVQ.jpg)

Comment: It looks like an Autolayout issue. Check your constraints in your Storyboard / Xib.

Comment: Just right now find that the it was the same question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907808/how-to-disable-horizontal-dragging-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/12671092#12671092 . Will try to use this fix for my site template. My site template is http://www.2ndexcers.co.nf/#. Will try to use this ready decision.

Comment: Actually, cant change something even with this answers.

Comment: Robotic Cat, thank you for advice! But still I can't figure out how to use Storyboard/Xib for web-debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in viewDidLoad method. This will force-fully set view inset to zero on all sides.

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: Hello Mohd! Do i need to add it in javascript file (how does to connect it to site)? Or that method works on C and it is available in app only?